# Jetty : Dynamically removing the registered servlet

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I created and started jetty server with WebAppContext. I can also add servlet to the WebAppContext with addServlet method. But I want to dynamically remove this servlet. 
How can I do this ? Something like removeServlet() is not provided in the WebAppContext.

Answer (score 22):

You need to do it manually (there probably should be a convenience method, but there isn't)

In Jetty 7 it would be something like (*untested*):

```java
public void removeServlets(WebAppContext webAppContext, Class<?> servlet)
{
   ServletHandler handler = webAppContext.getServletHandler();

   /* A list of all the servlets that don't implement the class 'servlet',
      (i.e. They should be kept in the context */
   List<ServletHolder> servlets = new ArrayList<ServletHolder>();

   /* The names all the servlets that we remove so we can drop the mappings too */
   Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

   for( ServletHolder holder : handler.getServlets() )
   {
      /* If it is the class we want to remove, then just keep track of its name */
      if(servlet.isInstance(holder.getServlet()))
      {
          names.add(holder.getName());
      }
      else /* We keep it */
      {
          servlets.add(holder);
      }
   }

   List<ServletMapping> mappings = new ArrayList<ServletMapping>();

   for( ServletMapping mapping : handler.getServletMappings() )
   {
      /* Only keep the mappings that didn't point to one of the servlets we removed */
      if(!names.contains(mapping.getServletName()))
      {
          mappings.add(mapping);
      }
   }

   /* Set the new configuration for the mappings and the servlets */
   handler.setServletMappings( mappings.toArray(new ServletMapping[0]) );
   handler.setServlets( servlets.toArray(new ServletHolder[0]) );

}
```

Comment: No problem - but if you like the answer, you should click on the tick (at the top right of the answer) to mark it as your accepted answer. That's the best way to say "thanks" on stack overflow.

Comment: Hey Tim. Although this solution works, I'm wondering about the re-mapping of servlets going on here. Does this code happen to re-set all of the servlets over again each time it is called? It seems like it would be troublesome if the server yanked all of the servlets down just to remove one of them and put the rest back up. This could possibly lead race conditions, if I am correct.