# remove a sevlet dynamically from embedded jetty server version 9

Tags: java, jetty, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

Hi everyone is there a method to remove a servlet or servletcontext from an embedded jetty server version 9 like remove servlet? I specify version because SO has an [answer for jetty version 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175304/2587435) but i have the same doubts about the technique used as mentioned in the comments on that thread

Comment: @PaulSamsotha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150730/jetty-dynamically-removing-the-registered-servlet

Comment: It's very difficult to safely remove a servlet (too intertwined with security constraints, filter chains, etc).  It would be easier to just write a Filter that rejects calls to "disabled" servlets instead.   Why do you need to do this?